# How can I make my User fields case insensitive during user-login?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to make my user login fields non case-sensitive for `username` and `email` only. I applied it to my models, but then I realized I should keep the data as is and true to itself. How can I apply case-insensitivity to the two fields mentioned above?

views.py

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    subscribed = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password','first_name','last_name','subscribed')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

model.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name','password']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: *then I realized I should keep the data as is and true to itself*: May I ask why?

Comment: Some users might prefer to have specific upper-cases for certain characters in their `username` or `email` (maybe not as much for email...). For this case, I would much rather have user validation be non-case sensitive. @LeMinaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `__iexact` lookup in your valiator, something like:

```
def validate(self, data):
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=data['username']).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("User already exists")
    return data
```

You might want to use `self.Meta.model` instead of hardcoding `User`.